# Facebook Video Posts with the same OG tags looks different

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook seems to change things fast.. All existing questions I have seen are older than facebooks "big image" posts, that this question is (partially) related to.

I'm testing Facebook interaction by including meta tags in my page to add a YouTube player as og:video on a page on my site.

All OG tags validate and I can successfully post links and get the video embeded. The problem I get is that while both the Facebook OG Debug Tool and the post does understand the title and description of the page, the post seems to behave strangely when played compared to a youtube link.

Look at the differences here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1piW.jpg

I have tried all combinations and order of OG tags I can think of, but I cannot seem to get the same result from my page link as I get from the YouTube link. And since the Facebook Debugger Sees the exact same values, I can not see how they are interpreted so differently..?

Here is the OG Debugger Comparison: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF1ur.png

Has anyone else experienced this, or is familiar with the inner workings of Facebook?

The pages used to test are these, although the one on my site might have changed when you read this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The behaviour is triggered by the size of the og-image, and even if I still cannot understand why the youtube link behaves differently with the exact same image url, I can workaround it by manually setting a smaller og:image.

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHXud.png